# Java - Initializing ArrayList with size then shrink

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that I want to convert this is my code :

```
ArrayList<PostWrapper> postWrapperList = listingWrapper.getData();
int size = postWrapperList.size();
ArrayList<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>(size);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    PostWrapper postWrapper = postWrapperList.get(i);
    if (postWrapper.isKindLink()) {
        Post post = postWrapper.getData();
        postList.add(post);
    }
}
postList.removeAll(Collections.singleton(null));
```

As you can see in this code I'm doing some kind of filtering so the final size can be smaller than the initial size. Currently I'm calling removeAll() to remove null object to shrink the ArrayList.

My question is which is more efficient, this way or just creating ArrayList without any initial size and then just let the ArrayList class handling the dynamic allocation?
I'm concerned with deallocating excess capacity that I reserved when creating the list.

Comment: What do you mean by "shrink" the list.  Are you expecting that some entries you added were actually null, and you want to remove those? Or are you concerned with deallocating excess capacity that you reserved when creating the list?  You cannot do the latter with `removeAll()` since unused capacity is not considered part of the list.  The question is not clear enough to be answered yet.

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm actually concerned with deallocating excess capacity that I reserved when creating the list. So based on your explanation, I don't need to do anything?

Comment: The excess capacity is just one reference per slot (4 or 8 bytes depending on the size of a pointer).  The list does not store empty instances of `Post`.  Unless the list size is in the hundreds of thousands, don't worry about it.  If you really want to do it you have to copy the list to a new one of the correct capacity.  BTW, this smells like premature optimization.

Comment: You can use  postList.trimToSize();  to trims the capacity of this ArrayList instance to be the list's current size. An application can use this operation to minimize the storage of an ArrayList instance.

Comment: @JimGarrison OK then, as I thought I just overthinked it! Thank you!

Comment: You could you trimToSize(), or create subArrayList of size equal to size of filtered objects, or create an array initially and then covert to array list.

Comment: And as @WalterM pointed out in his answer, there's always `trimToSize()` if you really, really need to do it and are sure you won't be adding any more elements.  But remember it costs time to do the copy.  I'd leave things alone until you can show you actually need to trim it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code from java.util.ArrayList

```
/**
 * Trims the capacity of this <tt>ArrayList</tt> instance to be the
 * list's current size.  An application can use this operation to minimize
 * the storage of an <tt>ArrayList</tt> instance.
 */
public void trimToSize() {
   modCount++;
   if (size < elementData.length) {
       elementData = (size == 0)
         ? EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA
         : Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, this code snippet might be helpful to you using Java 8's new stream utility:

```
List<Post> postList = postWrapperList.stream()
                          .filter(PostWrapper::isKindLink)
                          .map(PostWrapper::getData)
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```